# Router asking for login sometimes

Tags: wireless-router

I use the Wi-Fi provided in my hostel. Sometimes, when I open any website the router redirects it to a login page saying that I need to login to use the Wi-Fi hotspot service. It also shows something as Mikrotik router os.
The router  model is TP-Link Model No. TL-WR740N / TL-WR740ND.
Here is a screenshot of the login page:
[image]
What should I do?

Comment: It sounds like your registration is only good for a limited amount of time.  What is the problem with just registering again?

Comment: It doesn't have any registration. We need to simply connect and enter the Wi-Fi password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Mikrotik's Captive Portal (aka "wifi hotspot") login page.  Not sure why you would be getting that from a TP link router.
Is the TP link router yours and the Mikrotik belongs to the Hostel or what is the arrangement.

Really need more/better info to help but if the question is just "how can I log in" the simple answer is to get the hotspot credentials from whomever is the owner of the Mikrotik router.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is at a hostel with different users, this could be occurring because as other people sign in, you are being moved to the end of the queue and eventually off the list of users. The wireless router only has so many open accounts at one time. If you go off the list, you might have to login again.

Comment: How can I login?

Comment: if you are getting kicked off for another user the only thing you can do is sign in again and kick someone else off...rinse and repeat...

Comment: It doesn't have any registration or login. We need to simply connect and enter the Wi-Fi password.